# Difference with Mobile Native Dynamic Maps and Dynamic Maps cost and usage

Tags: android, maps

for what I understand, the only difference on being charged or not is the usage of a map ID for android.

when you are not using a map id, you are not billed for a map load, under the SKU: Mobile Native Dynamic Maps

am I right?
**ref:** https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing

while in here, it shows that it is per request
**ref:** https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/

so what does count as billed? the request or the map load? or a mapload is under an API request?

I'm doing this "add map", am I going to be billed for this?
**ref:** [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/maps-compose#:~:text=sync%20these%20changes.-,Add%20a%20map%20to%20your%20app,-The%20following%20example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/maps-compose#:%7E:text=sync%20these%20changes.-,Add%20a%20map%20to%20your%20app,-The%20following%20example)

I think that it is under the free part in the pricing, right?
**ref:** https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/
under SKU: Mobile Native Dynamic Maps?

Comment: I had the same doubt, asked a question inside cloud.google and they answered

"Yes, Dynamic maps for mobile is free only if it is not loaded with a Map ID otherwise it will be charged as "Dynamic street view"

I believe is free, but is necessary to try and need to be very carefull, can be billed some day.

Comment: ahhh, I'll take note of that, thanks.

Comment: You are right in your understanding that if you are not using a map ID in Maps SDK for Android, you will not be billed, for it will be under the SKU: Mobile Native Dynamic Maps which is free. However, if you use a map ID, it will be billed under the SKU: Dynamic Maps which costs 0.007 USD.

Also kindly note that all Maps product SKUs are charged per MAP LOAD except for Static and Dynamic Street View SKUs. ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-and-pricing/pricing#maps-product-skus

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need to add billing setup for your account.
Every time when your map fragment created that is considered as request and will be counted. As you are developing for android Apps then you need the Dynamic Maps SDK for android. For such 1000 requests It will cost you $7.

First thing you need to have a developer account and your payment(card) information should be added. Then create API and enable the Maps SDK in google cloud console. Add that API key your manifest.

Comment: OK, I understand is necessary to enable "Dynamic Maps", but without using MAP_ID is free?

Comment: Without API_KEY we cannot display the Map in our app.

Comment: it does say there is a $7 dollar for a thousand request.
though under those pricing, there is a linked text which says "Get mobile Dynamic Maps without Cloud-based maps styling at no cost", when clicked, there is a mentioned MAP_ID, wherein if you use a MAP_ID for modifications and styling; you'll get charged. the first SKU shows that it is not using a MAP_ID and the cost is 0.

Comment: Yes without map id, its free

Comment: without map id you will be billed for static maps. its not free